# Run Visual Studio 2013 solution with Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have an MVC application originally developed in VS2010.  We have Crystal Reports (CR) integrated into it and all works smoothly.

Now, I need to setup some new workstations which will have only VS2013.  I can run the site in VS2013, but only because I have VS2010 and previously installed the CR runtime files.  The new stations won't have VS2010 installed and the SAP installer will not run unless VS2010 is on the machine.  SAP will not provide a fix until early 2014 at the earliest.

The new workstations don't need to be able to modify the reports, so I don't care if the full CR application is installed, I just need it to be able to reference the runtime files so they can debug other areas of the application.

I cannot remove CR from the application at this time, and cannot install VS2010 on all the new workstations first.

I have tried putting the dlls in the bin folder of the site.  I have tried putting them in `C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/
    Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dec0de27/fa4bed84/` Nothing seems to work.

Where do I place the dlls so VS2013 can use them?  I know there has to be some way to do this because my workstation can run the site in VS2013 eventhough SAP hasn't released a 2013 version.

Here is the error when they try to run the applicaiton:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc' 
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an 
incorrect format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or 
assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc' or one of its 
dependencies. An attempt was  made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can 
be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why 
the assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is 
provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the 
assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key 
token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more 
information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Office/Documents/GIT/Site/site/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Office\Documents\GIT\Site\site\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: 
C:\Users\Office\Documents\GIT\Site\site\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
C:\Users\Office\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, 
partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/
Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dec0de27/fa4bed84/
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/
Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/dec0de27/fa4bed84/
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc/
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Office/Documents/GIT/
Site/site/bin/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing 
terminated.
```

This is the SAP discussion http://scn.sap.com/message/14614675#14614675

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal report is updated support for VS 2013
[Updated version document](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Answer (score 2):

Probably no longer relevant to you, but CR for VS2013 is now available in support pack 9. Note: You have to run the exe to get integration with VS IDE.

Download from: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: which exe i need to run for integrate it with vs

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found an answer.

If you install the CR x86 Redist MSI package (for some reason it HAS to be 32bit) it will allow you to run VS2013 without throwing an error.  You won't be able to modify the reports, but at least you can build your application.

Download the latest here:
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the horse's mouth:

CR for VS 2013 will not be available until early 2014. Please see this [thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3445061) and the referenced threats in it for more info.

Comment: I know it isn't available, that is why I said SAP hasn't created it.  I don't care if my coworkers can't edit the CR files, I just want them to be able to run the application.  I want to fix the missing reference error (I don't get it in VS2013) and don't know where to put the files so it will work

Comment: But without the correct runtime files for CR, VS will throw an error because it can't RUN the report portion that's in your app. So you could take the CR portion out of the app and everything would run fine in VS2013. CR for VS is needed if you have any CR code (Viewer, etc) in your app.

Comment: I think I need to work on how I word my questions.  You keep stating what I have already stated.  VS2013 IS able to run the application IF the runtime files are installed for VS2010 first.  However, the installer won't install unless VS2010 is on the workstation.  I have the dlls from the installer.  Where do I put the files so my coworkers running VS2013 can run the site in VS2013 just like I do?

Comment: Aaah! Now we're getting somewhere! I'm not sure what your specs are, but look in C:\Program Files\MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ There you should find a Crystal Directory with the runtimes in it. On the other hand, your coworkers could always install the free VS2010 Express version on their machines.

Comment: One has the express version, but the SAP installer will not run on the express version.  Also, a workstation that doesn't work has the exact same contents in that folder as my machine.

Comment: Well, I'm running out of ideas. Have you thought about posting on the SAP site?

Comment: I posted, so we will see if they can help.

Comment: Ok, please make sure to post an answer if they can help. I'm curious about this!