# is there any crystal report version for vs 2013 ???

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any crystal report version for vs 2013 ??? I have vs 2013 ultimate, more then 3 times I installed various CR but they are'nt show in the template form of VS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615711/run-visual-studio-2013-solution-with-crystal-reports

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. ETA March 2014 - http://scn.sap.com/thread/3445061

See also: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824